# VPN site-to-site with rv180 poor connection (4 Mbps)

Tags: networking, cisco, router

I have speed problems with 2 cisco rv180 using VPN Site-to-Site. According to cisco specifications, the IPsec Throughput is 50 Mbps. I have done many tests using Iperf on both sides (NY ans SC) and all I have is 4 Mbps of IPsec Throughput. The internet speed for SC are: Download:50 Mbps Upload: 4 Mpbs, for NY: Download: 25 Mbps Upload: 25 Mbps. I changed the default encryption and authentication to 3DES and MD5 and mode to Aggressive, to see if it can improves but nothing. I also tested using PPTP client from my home (Download: 50 Mbps Upload: 8 Mbps) using Iperf, I have the almost the same speed of VPN Throughput than the IPsec 4 Mpbs.

All the options for the firewall are disabled, Jumbo frames are enabled and the right MTU sizes applied, all these have been done by a cisco engineer but I'm still have poor VPN performance.

I'm wondering if the internet speeds have something to do with the VPN's bad performance.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: You missed out the important points: how are you testing (iperf has many options and modes), which results do you expect instead of what you are getting?

Comment: I was using the defaults options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm wondering if the internet speeds have something to do with the VPN's bad performance.>

You mean outside the following:

> The internet speed for SC are: Download:50 Mbps Upload: 4 Mpbs,

Where you say yourself you are limited to 4mbps upload from there. OBVIOUSLY you only can get the smallest speed of any element. So, getting data out of SC will be limited to 4Mbps. THe router will not magically make your internet providers limitation go away, you know.

Plus you REALLY should ask someone borderline professional about networks:

> All the options for the firewall are disabled, Jumbo frames are enabled and the right MTU 
>   sizes applied,

JUMBO frames? How is that relevant given that the traffic goes over the internet, where the max MTU is standard. Noone supports jumbo frames on the internet.